# Activate another adapter after performing outbound operation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Consider a flow in which the operation is as follows:

```
┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┬───┐
  ┌──────┐                                            │ A │
│ │Poller│                                            └───┤
  └──────┘  ┌────────────┐                ┌────────────┐   
│     │     │ Get local  │                │            │  │
      │     │    file    │   ┌────────┐   │SFTP file to│   
│     └─────▶'test1.txt' │───▶ Chnnl1 ├───▶   remote   │  │
            │            │   └────────┘   │            │   
│           └────────────┘                └────────────┘  │

│                                                         │
 ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┬───┐
                                                      │ B │
│                                                     └───┤

│        ┌────────────┐                ┌────────────┐     │
         │ Get local  │                │            │      
│        │    file    │   ┌────────┐   │SFTP file to│     │
         │'test2.txt' │───▶ Chnnl2 │───▶   remote   │      
│        │            │   └────────┘   │            │     │
         └────────────┘                └────────────┘      
│                                                         │
 ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─
```

The operation 'B' should execute after operation 'A' is successful. As per my knowledge, I need to use `request-handler-advice-chain` in `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` of 'A', but I have no clue how to invoke the 'B' from it. The piece I tried is given below. I tried using `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` but I am anable to make it work. Can anybody suggest a approach for invoking 'B' after 'A'?

```
    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="/local/dir1"
        channel="channel1"
        filename-regex="test./txt">

        <int:poller fixed-rate="60000"/>

    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="channel1"></int:channel>


    <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
        session-factory="sessionFactory"
        channel="channel1"
        remote-directory="/remote/dir">

        <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>

            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="successChannel" value="?"></property>
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="?"></property>
            </bean>

        </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>


    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="/local/dir2"
        channel="channel2"
        filename-regex="test./txt">

    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="channel2"></int:channel>

    <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
        session-factory="sessionFactory"
        channel="channel2"
        remote-directory="/remote/dir">
    </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you second part fully depends on the first one, you can't use `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` there. This one is a beginning of the flow and can only produce event periodically by the poller's trigger. There is, of course, the way to have it as `auto-startup="false"` in the B flow and start it after first one is successful, but is it really you are looking for... Well, I even would say that it is not an *operation*: there is no one-to-one relationship between the message send to the `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` and the whole flow started in the second  `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

I'm not sure what really is a dependency there, but you need to take a look into a simple  service activator to call `File.list()` or something similar which really already depends on the result from the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. Or really consider only just use Control Bus to `start()` that second `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus

Comment: Is this standard way to do it? Or my thinking is wrong? I am new to the spring integration as whole.

Comment: Your thinking is wrong. The Inbound Channel Adapter doesn't depend on the event from other process. It is a start of new process. You need to explain more your business requirement and I believe there is some other solution without a confusing ` <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` in B.

Comment: Okay. The above example was just a sample. I am asking in general, what should be done when there is a requirement of performing complex operations one after another?

Comment: Well, you also need to change your vision about Spring Integration: it's not for "tasking" - it's messaging. So, when you start think about integration flows as sending messages from one channel to another (or several of them), you start to see the point of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and something like `PublishSubscribeChannel` or even `RecipientListRouter`. On the other hand you even can use a `MessagingTemplate` from your code. Also you still need to understand that Inbound Channel Adapter is the beginning of flow and it can't be triggered from other flow via message